# How to extend a module function

Tags: ruby, module

What is the way to extend a module function? In the following, I want to use `B.foo`

```
module A
    module_function
    def foo; end
end
module B
    extend A
end
B.foo
```

but it returns the error:

```
private method `foo' called for B:Module.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use it directly you need to make it public as well.

```
module A
  module_function
  public
  def hello
    puts "Hello"
  end
end

module B
  extend A
end


B.hello
```

Answer (score 1):

From [documentation](http://ruby-doc.org/docs/ProgrammingRuby/html/ref_c_module.html#Module.module_function): "The instance-method versions are made private."

By extending the module B you've added function `foo` to object `B`. This is because in ruby module is also an object. You can check it by this:

```
B.respond_to?(:foo,true) #=> true
```